# How can I take downloaded files from browser's cache into my code?

Tags: webdriver, elixir, wallaby, hound

I would like to testing my site to ensure that some versions of documents and images are present when some user-agents are going to my site.
I'm preparing now wallaby with geckodriver and chromedriver for the starting point of such testing.
My main question at this point is:
**can I take some files from the browser cache using wallaby (of hound), and not download these files twice?**